# How to insert a unique value to a two dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

For this program, the user is asked for a value for each cell in the array, and they must be disallowed from entering a value that appears elsewhere in the structure. Note I can only use array, not use other data structure.

How can I modify my code to do this?

Here is my code:

```
public class UniqueArrayAdd {
  int i, j;

  public UniqueArrayAdd() {
    int[][] arr3 = new int[3][3];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr3.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a value");
            // What to do to check the duplication
            // If the input value is not duplicated then insert other wise               //give "Already exist" message
            arr3[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    // For printing array
    for (i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr3.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr3[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new UniqueArrayAdd();
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Do you mean _any_ unique value? If so, then for each cell in an `wxh` rectangle, insert the number `(x+y*w)`. Thus your first row will get `0, 1, 2, ... w-1` and your second row will get `w, w+1, w+2...` etc. They will all be unique, since no number is repeated more than once.

Comment: @halfer I think that the values come from the Scanner, so manual input. But more information would really be helpful!

Comment: @halfer I mean unique in term of if one value is inserted at any location in table rows or column then another time not insert again for example in two dimensional array 00 or 01 or 10 or 11 etc at any index.

Comment: OK. So, if the user enters a number that is already in use (in a cell they are not entering) it is rejected and they are asked to re-add a value?

Comment: @halfer yes exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach is to iterate over all elements of the array and compare. For this you can "reuse" the code that is printing the elements of the array.

I would try to move the code into a separate method for doing this. It can e.g. return true if the value is contained, false otherwise. Something like this

```
boolean exists(final int value) {
 for (i = 0; i < arr3.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr3.length; j++) {
      if (arr3[i][j]==value) {
        return true;    
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Freitag for answer.but please will you elaborate your answer i am just the begineer.

Comment: @AbubakarEhsas Updated my answer within an example

Comment: Thank you @Stefan your answer is helpful.

Comment: A better way is to check from 0 until i,j not length because the array will not be fully populated but filled with zeroes so the method has to have the following signature boolean exists(int value, int i,int j)

Comment: @fiirephil The example was intended to give an idea, not the solution ;) One should also think about the input `0` - it does not seem to be disallowed.

Comment: @Stefan when i call a method the loop terminate and print array with all 0 value please help me,